# Why is Karma starting my complete React App when unit testing a single utils function?

Tags: reactjs, karma-runner, karma-webpack

I am trying to use Karma to test my React JS app. 
However, it get all kind of errors because it is trying to load/start the complete app.
My first error was

> Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(…): Target container is not a
>   DOM element
>   Which appears in my entry.js that is listed in webpack as entry point, but I remove it in my karma.conf.js.

I solved it in the entry.js by adding the dom element in case it doesn't exists.
Then I it's trying to call the method "getCurrentLocation()" on some undefined history object, that appears in some module that isn't mine :(

Bottom line: why is karma loading/starting my complete app while just testing a single method in my utils.js.
My test.js currently looks like:

```
let Utils = require('../utils');
```

I commented al the rest to isolate the errors.
My karma.conf.js en webpack.config.js are listed below:
karma.conf.js:

```
let webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
webpackConfig.entry = {};

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: 'src/js/',
        frameworks: ['jasmine-jquery', 'jasmine'],
        files: [
            "**/tests/*.test.js",
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            "**/tests/*.test.js": ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
        },

        webpack: webpackConfig(),
        webpackMiddleware: {
            stats: "errors-only"
        },

        reporters: ['mocha'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        phantomJsLauncher: {
            exitOnResourceError: true
        },
        singleRun: false,
        concurrency: Infinity
    })
};
```

--- webpack.config.js:

```
"use strict";

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

let mode = process.env.WEBPACK_ENV;
let isProdBuild = mode === 'prod';
let isAcceptBuild = mode === 'accept';
let isTestBuild = mode === 'test';
let isTestRun = mode === 'testRun';
let isDev = mode === 'dev';
console.log("Mode: " + mode)

let devServer = {};
let devTool = 'source-map';
let plugins = [];

/* plugins.push(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
 {from: 'src/js/vendor.js', to: 'src/js/vendor.js'},
 ])); */

// Used to inject the entry.js.
plugins.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'index.tpl',
    inject: 'body',
}));

plugins.push(new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist/*'], {verbose: true}));

if (isProdBuild || isAcceptBuild) {
    plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true, sourceMap: true}));
    plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin());

    plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({'process.env': {'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')}}));

    let CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
    plugins.push(new CompressionPlugin({
        asset: "[path].gz[query]",
        algorithm: "gzip",
        test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
        threshold: 10240,
        minRatio: 0.8
    }));
}
else if (isDev) {
    devServer = {inline: true, port: 3000};
    devTool = 'inline-source-map';
}

if (!isTestRun) {
    plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'common',
        minChunks(module, count) {
            let context = module.context;
            return context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
        },
    }));

    plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: 'manifest'}));
}

module.exports = function (env) { 
    return {
        entry: {
            entry: ['./src/entry.js', './src/js/utils.js'],
        },
        devtool: devTool,
        devServer: devServer,
        output: {
            path: __dirname + '/dist',
            filename: '[name]-[hash].cache.js', 
            sourceMapFilename: '[name]-[hash].cache.js.map',
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { // The Babel loader:
                    test: /(\.jsx|\.js)$/, 
                    exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['babel-preset-es2015', 'babel-preset-react'].map(require.resolve),
                            plugins: ['babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-img-import'].map(require.resolve) 
                        }
                    }]
                },
                { 
                    test: /\.s?css$/,
                    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                },
                { 
                    test: /\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$/,
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: 'resources/images/[name]-[hash]-cache.[ext]'
                        }
                    }]
                },
                { 
                    test: /\.(otf|svg|eot|ttf|woff2?)(\?.*$|$)/,
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: 'resources/fonts/[name]-[hash]-cache.[ext]'
                        }
                    }]
                },
            ]
        },
        plugins: plugins,
    };
};
```